# null pointer access error with pageContext variable with JSP EL

Tags: jsp, jstl, servlet-4

I am getting a IDE error with JSP files containing the following EL snippet:

The error is:
**Null pointer access: The variable pageContext can only be null at this location**

IDE: Spring Tool Suite 4.11  (Eclipse 4.20)
Container: Tomcat 9
JDK:  AdoptOpen JDK 11

The issue appears to be only within the IDE - there is no runtime issue.

Here are the relevant portions of the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

i was making it more difficult than necessary.  Solution is:

```
<input type="hidden" id="pageContextRequestPath" value="<c:url value="/" />" />
```

note:  this solutions requires the following standard tag library

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```